# Can PHP SoapClient throw custom SoapFaults

Tags: php, soap-client, soapfault

Is it possible to map `\SoapFault` to custom Exceptions like you can with objects?

I'm accessing an ESP's SOAP service through their WSDL. The WSDL defines a set of fault objects. Is it possible to create custom Exception classes so that `\SoapClient` will throw those instead of the generic `\SoapFault`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offhand, the only suggestion I can make is using `set_exception_handler()` to catch the `\SoapFault` objects and re-throw them as custom exception instances.